# do_action_ref_array within constructor with $this passed as argument

Tags: php, wordpress

Can someone help me explain what is going on here? I am going through a Wordpress plugin. It has the following constructor function

```
protected function __construct() {
    do_action_ref_array( 'plugin_specific_action_name', array( $this ) );
    add_action( 'init', array( $this, 'init' ) );
}
```

My question is on the first line of the constructor. The action 'plugin_specific_action_name' didn't have any function associated anywhere. The action hook is plugin specific. Since it didn't have any function associated with it, what does it helps the plugin with.

The author has commented "Announce that the class is ready, and pass the object (for advanced use)". Can someone help me what exactly will that be used for? Why do I have to use this in the constructor function? What will be the advanced use cases I can use that for? Any help in clearing this for me will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Ok. do_action or do_action_ref_array is just a placeholder. Any custom behavior can be introduced here with help of add_action. If nothing is specified the action will be muted. So it is a place holder. The eye opener for me here is do_action can exist without add_action